# How to write csv files to S3 from inside a Job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I have a data backup system for customers of my app.  I gather up all associated csv files and zip them.  Once that zip file is complete, I attach it in an email.  This process breaks on heroku due to their file system.  I thought since heroku-16 we could write to the app/tmp directory and that this process might occur within the same transaction and the files would be fine, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I don't even seem to be writing the files to the tmp directory in production (in Dev I am).

So, what I would like to do instead is just write the csv files directly to S3, then Zip those files and also save the .zip to S3...then, pull that file as an email attachment.  To do this, I need to generate the csv files and write them to S3 from inside ActiveJob.  I use S3 already as part of ActiveStorage, but this process will not utilize ActiveStorage.

Is there's a command for me to manually direct upload to an S3 bucket.  I've been digging around in the docs, etc but don't see what I'm after.

## The Job (using /tmp)

```
 def perform(company_id, recipient_id)
    company         = Company.find(company_id)
    source_folder   = "#{ Rails.root }/tmp"
    zipfile_name    = "company_#{ company.id }_archive.zip"
    zipfile_path    = "#{ Rails.root }/tmp/#{ zipfile_name }"
    input_filenames = []

    # USERS: create a new empty csv file,
    # ... then add rows to it
    # ... and, add the file name to the list of files array
    users_file_name = "#{ company.name.parameterize.underscore }_users_list.csv"
    input_filenames << users_file_name
    users_csv_file = File.new("#{ Rails.root.join('tmp') }/#{ users_file_name }", 'w')
    users_csv_file << company.users.to_csv
    users_csv_file.close

    ...

    # gather up the created files and zip them
    Zip::File.open(zipfile_path, create: true) do |zipfile|
      input_filenames.uniq.each do |filename|
        zipfile.add(filename, File.join(source_folder, filename))
      end
    end

    puts "attaching data_export".colorize(:red)
    company.data_exports.attach(
      io: StringIO.new("#{ Rails.root }/tmp/company_14_#{ Time.current.to_date.to_s }_archive.zip"),
      filename: 'company_14_archive.zip',
      content_type: 'application/zip'
    )

    last_id = company.data_exports.last.id
    puts "sending mail using company.id: #{ company.id }, recipient_id: #{ recipient_id }, company.data_exports.last.id: #{ last_id }".colorize(:red)
    CompanyMailer.mail_data_export(
      company.id,
      recipient_id,
      last_id
    )
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can upload file like this on S3

```
key = "file_name.zip"
file_path = "tmp/file_name.zip"
new_s3_client = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'eu-west-1', access_key_id: '123', secret_access_key: '456')
new_bucket = new_s3_client.bucket('public')
obj = new_bucket.object(key)
obj.upload_file(file_path)
```